# ipad app - most views rotate ok. One view does not

Tags: xcode, ios5, rotation

I am building an iPad app where all views should autorotate. One view is giving me a headache.

I know that variants of this question have been asked a couple of times before, but I cannot find a working solution..

I flip to this view by calling a routine in the app. delegate. The code for this routine is:

```
- (void)flipToBack {
    //NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);

    DrawingViewController *drawView = [[DrawingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Draw" bundle:nil];
    [self setDrawingViewController:drawView];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:window cache:YES];

    [self.window addSubview:[drawView view]];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    //  NSLog (@" FINISHED ");
}
```

This is a view controller (mvc) with a UIView subview, the latter, where drawing takes place. Neither the mvc nor the subview are rotating properly.

The code I'm using to invoke the rotation in the mvc is:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
```

The mvc has two tool bars, top and bottom, and these need to resize. These should also stay top and bottom regardless of the rotation.

The project summary shows all orientations are supported, but I think that this is just for app. initialization.

I have all struts on for the mvc.

I'm building the toolbars like this:

```
UIInterfaceOrientation fieldOrient = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if ((fieldOrient == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (fieldOrient == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)) {
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, 1024, 35 );
        topToolbar.frame = frame;
    } else {
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, 768, 35 );
        topToolbar.frame = frame;


UIInterfaceOrientation fieldOrient = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if ((fieldOrient == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (fieldOrient == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)) {
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 650, 1024, 35 );
        bottomToolbar.frame = frame;
    } else {
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 950, 768, 35 );
        bottomToolbar.frame = frame;
```

I guess I'm missing something obvious.. Any help/pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for me was to present the view as a modal view. It's not ideal but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the frame in the will rotate to interface orientation method:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

    if ((toInterfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (toInterfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)) {
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 650, 1024, 35 );
        bottomToolbar.frame = frame;
    } else {
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 950, 768, 35 );
        bottomToolbar.frame = frame;
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could set the auto-resizing mask when creating your toolbar.

Comment: I apologize but I've added more  to the question, and to the code that might change your answer..